# How to Integarate Jmeter with Adobe Analytics

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, adobe-analytics

I have one requirement to use Adobe Analytics with Jmeter tests. so what ever the transactions going from my JMeter to my application, I need to analyse those in Adobe Analytics, so please suggest me how to integrate these two.

JMeter + Adobe Analytics

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be integrating JMeter testing on your web application. One option is to pass an additional request in the requests which you send to the web application. In your web application, you can check for this parameter (will know that it is from JMeter) and initiate the analytics code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

With API Username and Shared Secret (you can find them at your Account Information page) you should be able to execute necessary SOAP or REST request using JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

You will also need [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send i.e. X-WSSE header, [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header, etc.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more information on configuring JMeter for simulating web service requests.